# How to extract Hard disk serial number from string

Tags: javascript, node.js, hardware

I am using the following function to get serial number of HDD.

```
function getHDDSerialNumber() {
    var sys = require('util')
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {            
        console.log(sys.inspect(stdout, {showHidden: true, depth: null}))
    }
    exec("wmic DISKDRIVE get SerialNumber", puts);
}
```

The above function prints the string as shown below:

```
SerialNumber    \r\r\nS2SMJ9DD906854  \r\r\n\r\r\n
```

What I want to print (Just the serial number):

```
S2SMJ9DD906854
```

Is there any parameter to exec function that can give me just the serial number?

I would also like to know:

- If I reinstall my operating system, then will I get the same serial number using this method?
- Which version of Windows does support my code? I mean I am currently using Windows 10 and it returns me a (correct) serial number, but if my application is running on Windows XP, then will I get this serial number using this method?

Answer (score 0):

Since `\r` and `\n` represent `WhiteSpace` characters. You can replace all WhiteSpaces `\s` with nothing `""` using a regular expression

```
var theString = "\r\r\nS2SMJ9DD906854  \r\r\n\r\r\n";
var rgx = /\s/gi;
theString = theString.replace(rgx, "");
console.log(theString);
```

Comment: I am not sure if the above mentioned function returns the same string on all the computers. If you are a node developer then can you please try to run the above mentioned function in your computer?

Comment: I am not a Node developer, but like most other developers I have all sorts of environments loaded... If I run the command on the computer I'm running at the moment, I get the same number of lines you are getting, but I have as many serial numbers as I have hard drive in this computer.

Comment: FWIW, I ran `wmic DISKDRIVE get SerialNumber` in the Node.js command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your result to doing this:

```
var string = "\r\r\nS2SMJ9DD906854  \r\r\n\r\r\n";
string = string.trim();
console.log(string);
```

Comment: I am not sure if the above mentioned function returns the same string format on all the computers. If you are a node developer then can you please try to run the above mentioned function in your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Simply print output as below,

```
console.log(stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following codes work for me

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("wmic DISKDRIVE get SerialNumber", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) { 
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    //console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);

    let drives = stdout.split(os.EOL);
    console.log(drives[1].trim()); // Output : Frist Drive Serial number  
});
```